# How to fix this jar mismatch and found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar error?

Tags: android

I deleted my add from eclipse and imported a backup copy of it. Now the app doesn't run and i get the following errors. Please can you explain step by step to fix this error?

```
            Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
                  [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task] but not all the versions are identical   (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
                [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task] All versions of the libraries must be the  same at this time.
           [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task] Versions found are:
             [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task] Path: E:\facebook-android-sdk-     3.6.0\facebook\libs\android-support-v4.jar
                 [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task]   Length: 349252
                   [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task]     SHA-1:  612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
                   [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task] Path: E:\Android wrks\Task\libs\android-support- v4.jar
           [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task]     Length: 556198
                        [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task]    SHA-1:   4a6be13368bb64c5a0b0460632d228a1a915f58f
           [2014-02-14 14:09:19 - Task] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

After removing and adding v4 library again i get this error

```
                                Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define                  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityService InfoVersionImpl;
              [2014-02-14 14:21:03 - Task] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to  execute dex: Multiple dex files define                     Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityService         InfoVersionImpl;
            [2014-02-14 14:25:28 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define                Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityService     InfoVersionImpl;
        [2014-02-14 14:25:28 - Task] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to     execute dex: Multiple dex files define        Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityService      InfoVersionImpl;
           [2014-02-14 14:27:59 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define  Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityService InfoVersionImpl;
   [2014-02-14 14:27:59 - Task] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute  dex: Multiple dex files define         Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityService      InfoVersionImpl;
    [2014-02-14 14:28:29 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define         Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityService InfoVersionImpl;
        [2014-02-14 14:28:29 - Task] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to  execute dex: Multiple dex files define       Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityService InfoVersionImpl;
```

Comment: Does your project reference any android library?

Comment: Right click one of the projects: Android Tools > Add Support Library. Then in this same project copy the android-support-v4.jar and paste it in the other project. (override)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the latest `android-support-v4.jar` in both the application and in the Facebook sdk.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete android-support-v4.jar from your project
2. Add the same file from  Library project to your project

Comment: If you get `Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define ` this exception then once remove your library project which added to your project and once clean n refresh it and again add your library project and try. May it helps you..

Comment: (OR) 1. Close eclipse.
2. Delete bin folder inside your project folder.
3. Start eclipse and clean your project.
4. Now run and the problem should be gone

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps support-v4 libraries in your project and Facebook-sdk library is different. Put the same support libraries jars in your project and Facebook-sdk project.

Note: also you can update the support library in Facebook-sdk, it will not provide any changes.